# How do TASK MANAGER read the PROCESSES

Tags: windows

The search for the execution of processes has taken me to this question. How do the task manager read the processes that are running?? Is there any command that makes the task manager read the processes.

Please help me to getting to the answer.

Thank you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this article: [Enumerating All Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682623(VS.85).aspx)

It uses the [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682629(VS.85).aspx) Win32 call.