# Windows API's which will show the running processes

Tags: c, windows, winapi, visual-c++, process

I want to create a tool like mini task manager. I want to show all the running processes, cpu and memory usage. Can anybody tell me related api's which I can use for this. Any link to related web page will be appreciated. (I want dump of all the statistics of running processes, cpu and memory.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202003/how-do-i-see-if-another-process-is-running-on-windows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281205/get-the-process-handle-of-a-process-by-image-name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865152/how-can-i-get-a-process-handle-by-its-name-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112389/how-do-task-manager-read-the-processes

Comment: @karlphillip : Thanks for all the links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do that, you will need to [use the tool help functions to get snapshots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the system.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a code example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EnumProcess` and `openProcess` to do this.
Here is a complete sample code for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx