# How to get all process IDs?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows API's which will show the running processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593493/windows-apis-which-will-show-the-running-processes)

[image: all process id in process Hacker]

How do I get the process ID of all the processes of the iexplorer.exe? `getcurrentprocessid()` is getting the parent process id when I inject my DLL in the iexplorer.exe process.

How can I do this?

Comment: can you please elaborate the problem..........

Comment: when IE is opened with multiple tabs it has multiple PID... when i Inject my DLL in multiple Process of IE, with GetCurrentProcessId() function i am getting the parent process PID, that is only one PID i wanna get all the PID of IE

Comment: Recurse over that process children.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to just enumerate all processes on the system, and pick the ones that are IE. There are a few simple ways to get information about all processes running on the system:

1. [EnumProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), from PSAPI. This is probably the simplest but doesn't give much info; you need to use other APIs to gather the info you need (OpenProcess / [GetModuleFileNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).
2. [CreateToolhelp32Snapshot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (then [Process32First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Process32Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), from TlHelp32.h. Quite simple to use, and automatically gives you the EXE name so you can easily tell if it's iexplorer.exe.
3. WMI, as @nogard already mentioned.