# How can I determine whether FSLogix is running in C++/Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I am currently trying to fix a bug within our source code and it appears FSLogix is installed.  I want the code to do something different if FSLogix is running.  How can I achieve this.  Our source is Windows based.  Is there an FSLogix API?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593493/windows-apis-which-will-show-the-running-processes

Comment: I need more than if FSLogix is running ideally.  I need an API that I can access

Comment: Looks like two separate questions.